# System.XML Read values into an array

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, system.xml

I need to read all text values from a XML into a list...

My XML has the following format:

```
<MultiNodePicker type="content">
  <nodeId>52515</nodeId>
  <nodeId>52519</nodeId>
</MultiNodePicker>
```

My code:

```
string mystring= @"<MultiNodePicker type='content'>
  <nodeId>52515</nodeId>
  <nodeId>52519</nodeId>
</MultiNodePicker>";
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(mystring);
Console.WriteLine(doc.InnerText);  
List<string> ids = doc.GetTextValues???()
```

- option **text**: I select all text values, dont care about the XPath;
- option **XPath**: I select `MultiNodePicker/nodeId` values;
- option **childs**: I select values from all `nodeId` child nodes.

Comment: Permanent link: http://rextester.com/QJTRN53043

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a little bit of LINQ:

```
var ids = XElement.Parse(mystring)
    .Descendants("nodeId")
    .Select(x => x.Value); // or even .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Value));

foreach(var id in ids) {
    Console.WriteLine(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LinQ to XML:

```
string mystring = @"<MultiNodePicker type='content'>
<nodeId>52515</nodeId>
<nodeId>52519</nodeId>
</MultiNodePicker>";
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(mystring);
List<string> memberNames = XDocument.Parse(mystring)
.XPathSelectElements("//MultiNodePicker/nodeId")
.Select(x => x.Value)
.ToList();
```

Comment: this should be the XPath option